# Dummy as moderator in regression analysis

Tags: regression, interaction, panel-data

I am working on data about the food industry, where companies should be divided according to their region (Asia, Europe, and North America) via dummies. This is supposed to be the moderator variable.

However, there are companies which come from other regions that are not relevant and should be excluded from the dummies. This is not possible so far, as I need to implement four dummies then. R provides another column then, named "Dummies" without any data included.

Putting the script into the formula for the regression (`new Company Partners ~ closeness centrality companies + Degree centrality companies + citations`) is not working. How can I include the dummies into this equation?

Comment: You don't say what function you are trying to use in R, which makes it hard to answer your question, and I think your question more properly belongs on another stackexchange site, stackoverflow.com. However, are you aware of the function 'subset' in R? It would be an easy way to exclude data from regions that are not relevant to your analysis. If you weren't aware of 'subset', I suggest you do a basic R tutorial before starting your analysis, it's likely to help!

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to use a categorical variable (whether coded via dummy coding or some other way) as a moderator.

If you wish to exclude some companies, you can either delete them (via subset, for instance) or mark country as missing for those companies.

You do not need to do the dummy coding, R (or any other stat package) will do it for you.